# How to compare two time series with a GAM?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-additive-model

I recently got comments back from a review who suggested I use a gam to compare two time series to see what the trends are and if the two time series are different from one another. I'm am trying to figure out how this would work, as combining two time series seems misleading. Here is some made up example data:

```r
years =c(rep(2002:2020,2))
datatype=c(rep("DataSource1",19),rep("DataSource2",19))
ratio=c(3.6,5.3,2.5,6.8,8.5,4.3,2.5,9.1,5.2,4.3,1.0,2.8,2.36,5.3,2.8,5.6,7.4,5.8,6.5,0.23,0.2,0.5,0.75,0.24,0.56,0.89,0.78,0.35,0.21,1.8,1.4,0.25,0.68,0.23,0.45,0.67,0.58,0.68)
df<- data.frame(years,datatype,ratio)
df
```

Basically, I have a time period from 2020 to 2020. For each of those years, I calculated a ratio based off of datasource 1 and datasource 2. Datasource 1 obviously had a higher ratio than datasource2. For my analyses, I took a linear regression of each datasource to see if the ratio was increasing or decreasing over time. I also ran a Kruskal Wallis test to compare the ratios between datasource 1 and datasource 2.

I am now trying to compare the two using a gam, as the review pointed out that maybe the ratios do not follow a linear trend. Here is my gam code:

```r
gam1 <-gam(ratio~  s(years, bs = 'tp')+ datatype , data=df, family=gaussian(link = "identity"))
summary(gam1)
```

with the output

```r
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
ratio ~ s(years, bs = "tp") + datatype

Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           4.8242     0.3601   13.40 5.80e-15 ***
datatypeDataSource2  -4.2216     0.5093   -8.29 1.33e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df     F p-value
s(years) 2.709  3.371 0.899   0.499

R-sq.(adj) =  0.651   Deviance explained = 68.6%
GCV = 2.8123  Scale est. = 2.4638    n = 38
```

I see that the datasource is important and not the year. I thought about doing an interaction term but that would negate the use of the gam.

I guess I'm asking if this method makes sense? For some reason I think it is not correct but I'm trying to follow the reviewers suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The model you fitted says the data can be explained by a single common trend for both series but that those series are offset from one another by some amount `-4.2216`.

In the linear model version you would typically have:

```r
lm1 <- lm(y ~ years + datatype + years:datatype, data = df)
```

where the `years:datatype` is a continuous-factor interaction that allows the slope of the trend to vary between groups.

The equivalent in the GAM framework is a factor-smooth interaction, of which there are several types in {mgcv} but the factor-by version seems most suited to the question at hand.

Basically you want to estimate a model with a single trend and then one with a a factor-smooth interaction to get two trends, one per series, and then compare the estimated trends.

```
gam1 <- gam(ratio ~ datatype + s(years) , data = df, method = "ML")
gam2 <- gam(ratio ~ datatype + s(years, by = datatype), data = df, method = "ML")
```

The you could use `AIC(gam1, gam2)` or `anova(gam1, gam2, tests = "LRT")` to compare the models to see which is the better descriptor of the data.

Using `gratia::difference_smooths()` on `gam2` you could estimate the difference between the two trends and see where 0 (difference) was excluded from the (simultaneous) confidence band.

Alternatively, you could use the ordered factor parameterisation to to fit something that is much closer to the ANOVA- (ANCOVA)-like parameterisation for the linear model that I showed:

```r
df <- transform(df, odatatype = ordered(datatype))

gam3 <- gam(ratio ~ odatatype + s(years) + s(years, by = odatatype),
            data = df, method = "ML")
```

wherein the first `s()` term is for the reference level of the (ordered) factor `odatatype`, while the second `s()` with the `by` term is a smooth *difference* between the smooth for the reference level and each of the other levels - in your case as there are two series, the second `s()` is the smooth difference between the two series.

I have a couple of blog posts that cover this in more detail (although they do all the computation of differences of smooths for `gam2` by hand - my {gratia} package has `difference_smooths()` to do this for you now):

1. https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/
2. https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/12/14/difference-splines-ii/

Also worth noting: you should really fit GAMs in {mgcv} using REML or ML smoothness selection, not GCV selection (the latter can undersmooth in some situations) and that for a models you want to compare that differ in their fixed effects you should use REML to fit the models, hence my using `method = "ML"`.

Finally, a ratio shouldn't be negative and hence typically would have a decreasing variance as the ratio tends towards 0. This implies the variance increase as the ratio tends away from 0. This non-constant variance can very well cause the assumptions of the Gaussian conditional distribution of the response to be violated. If you see a wedge of residuals in the model diagnostics plots (`gam.check(model)` or `gratia::appraise(model)`) then you should consider a different conditional distribution for the response - `family = Gamma(link = "log")` is often used for example.